# Function similar to ST_SetValue in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to extract pixel values from raster data using a grid, however using join, clippings take too long to process. I found out  ST_SetValues (https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetValues.html) can **modify** data by specifying starting point, height, and width. In addition, this function executes fast enough compared to join and clipping. Is there any function that behaves the same as ST_SetValues but only **extracts** pixel values?

Comment: You can extract band values at raster grid indices (row and column) via `ST_Value`. If your overlay vector grid is not aligned with the inherent raster grid, find an affine transformation to correlate indices, or resample, or pre-bin the raster grid cell indices to vector grid indices

Comment: @geozelot thanks for response. Can you share some examples or materials related to your mentioned methods ? I have tried `st_value` together with point coordinates and st_intersects. Unfortunately that was also to long.

Comment: Not without knowing your data setup. The general idea is to access the raster values by grid indices, rather than a vector transformation and subsequent intersection. I.e. if your vector grid aligns with the raster grid, use (row,column) indices to fetch the respective raster cell band values.

Comment: For ST_Value() to be fast your raster have to be tiled with the -t option at importation time. Read the doc...